What is the actual use of local guard on a login route in nest js, that under the hood is using auth service which generates token on correct match?
[AuthController code](https://i.sstatic.net/TpKVgh6J.png) [Localstrategy code:](https://i.sstatic.net/EdFhToZP.png) [Auth service code:](https://i.sstatic.net/gYA5LJSI.png) [Jwt strategy code](https://i.sstatic.net/XGwotIcg.png)
for a protected route I am using the JWT guard and that guard uses the jwt strategy to read and validate token from Authorization headers. I get the use of it that it actually does something but what does local guard does here?
I have just made two routes, one route is /login here if you send correct credentials you get your jwt token from auth service.
you have to pass this token on authorization headers to validate yourself on the next route i.e /status. I am totally getting the use of the jwt guard and jwt strategy but not the local guard and local strategy. I could have just used the auth service directly in the controller for /login.
the strategy is just returning me the token I could have used a auth service for this straight up right? Am I missing something?

this is also my question. I think it doesn't need to write a guard for login route
